# How to calculate sum of only last elements in list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple question, that I hope Python can do easily for me.

I would like to use the sum function on an array.

The array is a little complicated however it has the following structure:

```
[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],..]
```

I want to sum up all the `z` elements:

```
sum([[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],..]) = z1+z2+...
```

Can I do this?

Comment: `sum(i[-1] for i in lst)`. You should do more research

Comment: Yes you can. Give it a try. Someone will help you if you show us where you got stuck. Hint: Have a look at the `zip()` function. There are other ways to do it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have your list declared as follows:

```
myList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

---

There are several ways you can do that, the methods listed below are all equivalent:

```
sum(x[-1] for x in myList) # execution time: 0.000125 - 0.00015 (most efficient)

sum(c for a,b,c in myList)  # execution time: 0.000135 - 0.0003

sum(myList[x][-1] for x in range(len(myList))) # exec. time: 0.00017 - 0.00045
```